# latex equation is logging a "missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices

I have a big document and all was working good. I made a change into the parameters of the equation and now this is not compiling.

I use XeLaTeX to compile normally. 
[image: I need a equation like this]

```
 \begin{equation}           

 \begin{bmatrix}
    V_{as}\\ 
    V_{bs}\\ 
    V_{cs}
    \end{bmatrix} 

= 

\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
R_s & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & R_{s} &0 \\ 
0 &0  &R_{s} 
\end{smallmatrix}\right)

\begin{bmatrix}
i_{as}\\ 
i_{bs}\\ 
i_{cs}
\end{bmatrix}
+
p\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
L_{aa} & L_{ab} &L_{ac} \\ 
L_{ba} & L_{bb} &L_{bc} \\ 
L_{ca} & L_{cb} &L_{cc}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)

\begin{bmatrix}
i_{as}\\ 
i_{bs}\\ 
i_{cs}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
e_{as}\\ 
e_{bs}\\ 
e_{cs}
\end{smallmatrix}\right) .

\label{ec:DCBrushless}
\end{equation}
```

However when I compile, I get this

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.81
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again>
\par
l.81
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.82 \begin{bmatrix}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.86 \end{bmatrix}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.90 \left
(\begin{smallmatrix}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.95
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.96 \begin{bmatrix}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
```

Comment: Untested: Remove the empty lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to removing the blank lines in the `equation` environment to remove the immediate source of the error message(s), you should also aim to make your notation a bit more consistent. For instance, you may wish to use round parentheses uniformly for all matrices and vectors -- alternatively, use square brackets uniformly for these objects -- and using the same font sizes for matrices and vectors. (Vectors, after all, are just single-column or single-row matrices.)

The following example implements these ideas. The instruction `\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}` reduces the intercolumn whitespace in the matrices; it is used to ensure that both the math itself and the equation number fit on the same line. Assuming you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, the code below should compile equally well under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{ec:DCBrushless}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{pmatrix}
    V_{as}\\
    V_{bs}\\
    V_{cs}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
R_s & 0 &0 \\
0 & R_{s} &0 \\
0 &0  &R_{s}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
i_{as}\\
i_{bs}\\
i_{cs}
\end{pmatrix}
+
p\begin{pmatrix}
L_{aa} & L_{ab} &L_{ac} \\
L_{ba} & L_{bb} &L_{bc} \\
L_{ca} & L_{cb} &L_{cc}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
i_{as}\\
i_{bs}\\
i_{cs}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
e_{as}\\
e_{bs}\\
e_{cs}
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There mustn't be any empty lines within `equation` -- removing them and (adding a `\begin{equation}`) makes this compile

No further comments on the style of the equations please -- it's from the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{as}\\ 
V_{bs}\\ 
V_{cs}
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
R_s & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & R_{s} &0 \\ 
0 &0  &R_{s} 
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{as}\\ 
i_{bs}\\ 
i_{cs}
\end{bmatrix}
+
p\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
L_{aa} & L_{ab} &L_{ac} \\ 
L_{ba} & L_{bb} &L_{bc} \\ 
L_{ca} & L_{cb} &L_{cc}
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{as}\\ 
i_{bs}\\ 
i_{cs}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
e_{as}\\ 
e_{bs}\\ 
e_{cs}
\end{smallmatrix}\right) .
\label{ec:DCBrushless}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should work on the style of the equations even if it's from the OP `:-P`

Comment: @RomainPicot: No -- I would advise to use parentheses instead of square brackets for the vector

Comment: `mathtools` provides `psmallmatrix`, saves a bit of typing.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, but the question is not on **improve my style** ;-)